# Javascript Week Schedule Functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, schedule

I have a security camera set up in our shop. I want it to be scheduled to turn to a specific preset at different times throughout the week.

The code I have at present is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'language='javascript'>
var IPandPort = "ip:port
var user = "user"
var pwd = "pass"
var poPreset = "31"; 
var shopPreset = "33";
function shop_preset()
{
    action_zone.location ='http://'+IPandPort+'/'+'decoder_control.cgi?user='+user+'&pwd='+pwd+'&command='+shopPreset;
}

function postoffice_preset()
{
    action_zone.location ='http://'+IPandPort+'/'+'decoder_control.cgi?user='+user+'&pwd='+pwd+'&command='+poPreset;
}

</SCRIPT>

<input id="Post Office" type="button" value="Post Office" onclick="doFunction(postoffice_preset());" />
<input id="Shop" type="button" value="Shop" onclick="doFunction(shop_preset());" />

<IFRAME style="DISPLAY: none" src="" name=action_zone>
</IFRAME>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want to achieve in the simplest manner is to have it so:
Mon - Fri:
7am - postoffice_preset()
6pm - shop_preset()

Sat:
7am - postoffice_preset()
1pm - shop_preset()

Sun:
Do Nothing. ie: It stays on the shop_preset() that was previously set.

I am not certain if this is entirely possible. This will be running in Internet Explorer on a minimized window that will never be interacted with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `setInterval()` to achieve this.

[window.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Then your code could be something around these lines:

```
var IPandPort = "ip:port";
var user = "user";
var pwd = "pass";
var poPreset = "31"; 
var shopPreset = "33";
var nIntervId;
// When the window is loaded, run the schedule.
window.onload = schedule();

function schedule() {
    // If there's a timer already running, clean it.
    if (typeof(nIntervId) != "undefined") {
        clearInterval(nIntervId);
    }

    // Run the positionCamera function every minute.
    nIntervId = setInterval(positionCamera, 60000);
}

function positionCamera() {
    var now = new Date();
    var weekDay = now.getDay();
    var hour = now.getHours();

    // Mon-Sat, 7am.
    if (weekDay >= 1 && weekDay <= 6 && hour == 7) {            
        postOfficeCamera();
    }
    // Mon-Fri, 6pm. Sat, 1pm. Sun, 24h.
    else if ((weekDay >= 1 && weekDay <= 5 && hour == 18) || 
             (weekDay == 7 && hour == 13) || 
             weekDay == 7) {            
        shopCamera();
    }    
}

function shopCamera() {
    action_zone.location ='http://'+IPandPort+'/'+'decoder_control.cgi?user='+user+'&pwd='+pwd+'&command='+shopPreset;
}

function postOfficeCamera() {
    action_zone.location ='http://'+IPandPort+'/'+'decoder_control.cgi?user='+user+'&pwd='+pwd+'&command='+poPreset;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5VJjy/4/)

Comment: Perfect. Just a small dive further I found was helpful, was instead of letting the code sending the command every minute for the entire hour, I also added, var minute = now.getMinutes(); and also checked that it is minute == 0, so it only sent the command once. It also allowed me to do things at more specific times. Ie: if (hour == 18 && minute == 15){}. :)

Comment: Good idea. You turned it into a much better solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you won't find anyone that will code this out for you here; that's not what we do.

I would create a rules-engine of sorts. Program your schedule somewhere, that regularly check your schedule and do stuff.

Something like this:

```
(function() {
    var cameraInterval,
        zones = {
            'postoffice': 31,
            'shop': 33
        },
        zoneSchedule = {
            // Monday @ 7am
            107: zones.postoffice,
            // Monday @ 6pm
            118: zones.shop,

            // Tuesday @ 7am
            207: zones.postoffice,
            // Tuesday @ 6pm
            218: zones.shop,

            // Wednesday @ 7am
            307: zones.postoffice,
            // Wednesday @ 6pm
            318: zones.shop,

            // Thursday @ 7am
            407: zones.postoffice,
            // Thursday @ 6pm
            418: zones.shop,

            // Friday @ 7am
            507: zones.postoffice,
            // Friday @ 6pm
            518: zones.shop,

            // Saturday @ 7am
            607: zones.postoffice,
            // Saturday @ 1pm
            613: zones.shop
        },
        updateCamera = function() {
            var now = new Date(),
                nowIndex = now.getDay() + ('0' + now.getHours()).slice(-2),
                zoneCommand = zoneSchedule[nowIndex];

            // Only run this command if the current day/time is in the schedule
            if (zoneSchedule.hasOwnProperty(nowIndex)) {
                action_zone.location ='http://'+IPandPort+'/'+'decoder_control.cgi?user='+user+'&pwd='+pwd+'&command='+zoneCommand;
            }
        };

    // Check the schedule every hour
    cameraInterval = window.setInterval(updateCamera, 600000);
})();
```

**NOTE:** This will not work out-of-the-box. You will need to customize and tweak it to make it work for your specific application.

If you decide to give this a go and run into problems, please post a new question with your specific problem.

Comment: Terrible sorry if I came off as if I wanted someone to write the entire code for me. That was not my intention. Just wanted someone to show me the rough way. But MelanciaUK has very kindly done so for me.